# Ruby on Rails: Select from database where column equals a value from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

If I have an array of IDs from a table (table1) in my database. Is there a way of querying another table (table2) to select all the records where a column equals a value equal to one of the IDs from table1.

My code so far is:

```
LabQuestion.where("product_id=#{Product.where(:brand_id => brand_id).pluck(:id)}")
```

In this code, I am trying to retrieve all the Lab Questions which are linked to all the products from a brand. This code does not work, but I've tried to demonstrate my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have setup your relations properly, you can use [`joins`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) to join the two tables and query them like this:

```
LabQuestion.joins(:product).where(:products => { :brand_id => brand_id })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use includes instead of joins as below

```
LabQuestion.includes(:product).where(:products => { :brand_id => brand_id })
```

Comment: You *can* use `includes`, but it's not recommended in this case.